# Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference 5

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Help I dont know whats wrong ._. i checked instance and names still not right.
I hope anyone can help me with the fix

i added void and removed still no changes. i renamed all the frames and put the same name but still nothing

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at fef_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

My code i checked everything

```
stop();

header_mc.home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gohome);
header_mc.logo_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gohome);

function gohome (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(1)
}

header_mc.about_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goabout);

function goabout (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(2)
}

header_mc.image_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goimage);

function goimage (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(3)
}

////////Button 1//////////
thumb1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GetFirstImage)
function GetFirstImage (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(4)
}
////////Button 2//////////
thumb2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GetSecondImage)
function GetSecondImage (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(5)
}
////////Button 3//////////
thumb3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GetThirdImage)
function GetThirdImage (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(7)
}
////////Button 4//////////
thumb4_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GetForthImage)
function GetForthImage (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(6)
}

header_mc.contact_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gocontact);

function gocontact (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(7)
}

header_mc.demo_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, godemo);

function godemo (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(8)
}
```

Comment: What line of code is throwing the error? (Run in debug mode)

Comment: add this code at the top, and see which of them is undefined: 
`trace(header_mc.home_btn,header_mc.logo_btn,header_mc.about_‌​btn,header_mc.image_‌​btn,thumb1_btn,thumb‌​2_btn,thumb3_btn,thu‌​mb4_btn,header_mc.co‌​ntact_btn,header_mc.‌​demo_btn);`